# MVC 3 - img alt HTML tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following HTML from MVC1.

```
<img alt="<%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %>" src='<%= this.Url.Action("Image", 
"Products") + "/" + item.ID.ToString()%>' width="64" height="64" />
```

How would I use this for MVC 3, I have tried the following it's not working...

```
<img alt=" @Html.Encode(item.Name)" src='<@this.Url.Action(("Image", 
"Products")) + "/" + Picture1.SubProductCategoryID.ToString()>' 
width="64" height="64" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean for Razor, not for MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions but:

```
<img  alt="@item.Name"
      src='@(Url.Action("Image",  "Products") + "/" + Picture1.SubProductCategoryID.ToString())'
      width="64"
      height="64" />
```

If you have a statement instead of a simple action invocation, you need to surround the entire statement with parens `()`.  Also, you needed to drop the `<>` around the helper.  @SLaks is right about not needing the `Html.Encode`, too.

Comment: @SLaks - just getting around to that when you commented. That's what happens when you cut/paste and don't see everything at once. FWIW, your answer is better but I'm leaving mine since sometimes it is necessary to use the parens for a statement, for example: `@(foo == bar ? Url.Action("Index","Foo") : Url.Action("Index","Bar"))`

Comment: Thanks guys I believe this has been solved. I hope it is OK to close this post and open a new one. The reason is that I am trying to upload a image from a database in MVC 3 but it fails.

Comment: @DiscoDude -- it would probably be better to simply pass the id in as route value.  `@Url.Action( "image", "products", new { id = Picture1.SubProductCategoryID } )` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `src` to

```
src="@Url.Action("Image", "Products")/@Picture1.SubProductCategoryID"
```

Also, [don't call `Html.Encode`](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/dont-call-htmlencode-in-razor.html); Razor does this for you.